# How to compute SFS(Sequential feature selection) with "multiple class" SVM？

Tags: matlab, svm

I can use sequentialfs function to compute the SFS with two-class SVM.
(means the binary output [0 1])

below is my code：

```
%% x=features, y=binary response.
c = cvpartition(y,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter'); [fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,x,y,'cv',c,'options',opts)

function err = SVM_class_fun(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest)
model = svmtrain(xTrain,yTrain,'Kernel_Function','polynomial','polyorder',2, 'boxconstraint', 1);
 err = sum(svmclassify(model, xTest) ~= yTest); end
```

My issue is how to compute SFS when y is not binary.

I can't get it to work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `svmtrain` is only for binary classification. If you would include the error message you get when `y` is not binary, then we could know.

There are several implementations of multi-class SVM in Matlab including:

(1)[This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39352-multi-class-svm) from the file exchange which apparently uses a syntax similar to `svmtrain`, (2) [and this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationecoc-class.html) from Mathworks itself which uses a slightly different structure.

I haven't personally used it, but I would start with (1) since the syntax is just the same as `svmtrain`, however it may lack the kernel and boundary options you use. Good luck!

Comment: now I exchanged the function for svm, which is "fitcecoc", but the compiled answer was not good performance and I can't sure the answer be correct,